# php file only works if file begins with php code

Tags: php, html, setcookie

I am new to php and wonder what am I missing about the rules for interleaving html and php code.

This is now the second time I run into a situation where a php file only works if my php tag is at the beginning of the file.  This is not the case for all my files.  I wonder why that might be.

Here is an example:

My file structured as follows works just fine:

```
<?php

... my php code

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Authentication</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I move that html block at the top (which is what I want ultimately since I use some echo statements in my php code), and leave only the following at the bottom:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then some portion of the php code do not work.  For example, my setcookie function no longer sets a cookie (though it does not error out) while I can still run sql queries or echo statements just fine.  I ran into a similar issue with a complete different code taken straight out of a tutorial site: the example would only work if the code started with

Comment: For Cookies, or sessions .. you must issue the code that makes the cookie or the session before you output anything in the page, i.e. any echo statement or html code outside of <?php ?> tags.

Comment: Google the exact error message you get when you cannot set a cookie and you will find a couple million hits explaining what's going on. Briefly: some things are done through HTTP headers, and once you start outputting content you can't "go back" and add more headers.

Comment: You should not put the HTML on top: save all the information you want to echo into PHP variables and when you print the HTML use php snippets like: `<input type='text' value='<?php print $variable;?>'>`

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding so quickly.  This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some operations (like writing a cookie) must be performed by PHP before any output is sent to the browser, because those operations involve setting response headers (which are always sent before any other content). That seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/setcookie):

> **setcookie()** defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent *before* any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including `<html>` and `<head>` tags as well as any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Give those links a look, they will explain something, and never forget to ask here on stackOverflow

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, you can place the  tag practically anywhere in the html code, as long as it's structured correctly.

However, there are some functions in php requires that no output is made before it is executed, like setcookie, setsession, header .. etc.

The output here is either;
   a. an echo statement in php code.
   b. an html code before the  tag that the function is in.

and as for that some code in php doesn't work. 
Usually, if you have any problem in your code, that php code doesn't work. So, it's better to check if it syntax correct or not before that.